# how to make a for loop lottery statement work?

Tags: loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For Loop in JavaScript - Lottery Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093050/for-loop-in-javascript-lottery-website)
>   [code javascript quick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093832/code-javascript-quick-answer)

```
var firstInput = document.luckForm.numberBox.value;
var secondInput = document.luckForm.numberBox2.value;
var thirdInput = document.luckForm.numberBox3.value;

for (firstInput = 0; firstInput <= 10; firstInput++) 
{
    if (firstInput = luckyNumber) 
    {
        if (secondInput = luckyNumber2) 
        {
            if (thirdInput = luckyNumber3) 
            {
                alert('Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1000!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to change this code (see below) into a for loop code (see above), very simple with no arrays. I am not sure how I can do this. It is supposed to be for a lottery, you can type in three numbers and if they are correct you would get the message that you win 1000 pounds. I have googled a lot but I cannot make sense of the for loop statement:(

```
if (firstInput == luckyNumber && secondInput == luckyNumber2 && thirdInput == luckyNumber3 || firstInput == luckyNumber && secondInput == luckyNumber3 && thirdInput == luckyNumber2 || firstInput == luckyNumber2 && secondInput == luckyNumber3 && thirdInput == luckyNumber || firstInput == luckyNumber2 && secondInput == luckyNumber && thirdInput == luckyNumber3 || firstInput == luckyNumber3 && secondInput == luckyNumber && thirdInput == luckyNumber2 || firstInput == luckyNumber3 && secondInput == luckyNumber2 && thirdInput == luckyNumber)
{
    alert('Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1000!');
}
```